# This given text is in json format.As i am new to python so tell me how can i get id from user only

Tags: python, twitter, social-networking

```
  "user":{"contributors_enabled":false,
  created_at":"Wed Jul 21 00:30:00 +0000 2010","
 default_profile":false,
 "default_profile_image":false,"description":"",
 "entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},
 "favourites_count":0,"follow_request_sent":false,
```

Comment: this is the remaining part of a code from which i have to extract id:               has_extended_profile":false,"id":168873000,
"id_str":"168873000","is_translation_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"lang":null,"listed_count":0,
"location":"","name":"elaine cristina lima","notifications":false,"profile_background_color":"FF6699",

Comment: *As you are new to python*, read about `JSON` from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: @AhsanMansoor Did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `id` from `user` like this -

***Example***

```
records = {
    "user":{
            "contributors_enabled":false,
            "created_at":"Wed Jul 21 00:30:00 +0000 2010",
            "default_profile":false,
            "default_profile_image":false,
            "description":"",
            "entities":{
                        "description":
                                    {"urls":[]}
                        },
            "favourites_count":0,
            "follow_request_sent":false,
            "has_extended_profile":false,
            "id":168873000,
            "id_str":"168873000",
            "is_translation_enabled":false,
            "is_translator":false,
            "lang":null,
            "listed_count":0,
            "location":"",
            "name":"elaine cristina lima",
            "notifications":false,
            "profile_background_color":"FF6699"
            }
}
```

*Code:*

```
records['user']['id']   #168873000
```

This will return `id` from `user`

***Reference:***

https://realpython.com/python-json/

*EDIT*

Code to get `id` from `user` by reading from .json file -

```
def records_from(json_path):
    '''Return the records read from .json file json_path
    '''
    with open(json_path, 'r') as json_file:
        records = json.load(json_file)
    return records

jsondata = records_from(filename)
print(jsondata['user']['id'])  # prints 168873000
```

Comment: I tried using this code:                                                                                              
 with open("D:/FYP/newsnet/g1seq.json","r",encoding="utf8")as read_file:
    data = read_file.read()                                                                                                              
jsondata=json.loads(json.dumps(data))
print(jsondata['user']['id']) but getting this error              TypeError                              
----> 9 print(jsondata['user']['id'])
     
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @AhsanMansoor Okay. Editing my answer. Try that solution.

Comment: can you give me your email address so that you could see in which format my data is..as it doesn't include any records like thing because i know this edited code will not work for me this time too

Comment: I tried with the same data you provided. You can take formatted data which is under Example in this answer.

Comment: the data I wrote here is incomplete

Comment: You can post the complete data

Comment: when I was posting, it showed errors like indentation etc so i skipped and posted my concerned part of a data.

Comment: this is how my data is beginning in the file                                      {"contributors":null,
"coordinates":null,
"created_at":"Fri Apr 06 09:27:40 +0000 2012",
"display_text_range":[0,85],
"entities":{"hashtags":[],
"symbols":[],
"urls":

Comment: If your data is formatted in .json file, you will right output using my solution above. Try online to format you.json data